# perl - replace every nth (and multiples) occurrences of a character with another character

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, command-line

Does anyone know any unix commands/perl script that would insert a specific character (that can be entered as either hex (ie 7C) or as the actual character (ie |)) in the position of the nth recurring occurence of a specific character. 
ie `perl script.pl "," 3 "|" data.txt`
would replace every 3rd,6th,9th...etc comma with a pipe.

So if data.txt had the following before the script was run:

```
fd,3232,gfd67gf,
peas,989767,jkdfnfgjhf,
dhdhjsk,267,ujfdsy,fuyds,637296,ldosi,fduy,
873,fuisouyd,try
save,2837,ipoi
```

It should then have this after the script was run:

```
fd,3232,gfd67gf|
peas,989767,jkdfnfgjhf|
dhdhjsk,267,ujfdsy|fuyds,637296,ldosi|fduy,
873,fuisouyd|try
save,2837,ipoi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small perl hack to solve the problem. Using the `index` function to find the commas, modulus to replace the right one, and `substr` to perform the replacement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my $x=index($_,","); 
    my $i = 0; 
    while ($x != -1) {
        $i++; 
        unless ($i % 3) { 
            $_ = substr($_,0,$x) ."|". substr($_,$x+1); 
        }
        $x = index($_,",",$x + 1) 
    } 
    print;
}
```

Run with `perl script.pl file.csv`.

Note: You can place the declaration `my $i` before the `while(<>)` loop in order to do a global count, instead of a separate count for each line. Not quite sure I understood your question in that regard.

Comment: It should be a global count, ie not on a per line basis. Also, how would you make the script accept the "|", "," and 3 as arguments?

Comment: @toop `my $find = shift; my $replace = shift; my $count = shift` will remove them from `@ARGV` and allow the diamond operator to process the file argument. You can use `0x7C` or `"|"` (must be quoted to prevent shell interpretation). If you want to use `7C` you must first convert it using the `hex` function.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to get them all working due to your help except that it replaces literally 0x7C instead of with |.

Comment: @toop Well, if you are using a number, you must convert it to a character first, naturally. Perl cannot decide on its own if you are using a numerical argument or not. Use `chr($number)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
my ($from, $to, $every, $fname) = @ARGV;
my $counter = 0;
my $in = read_file $fname;
my $out = $in;
# copy is important because pos magic attached to $in resets with substr
while ($in =~ /\Q$from/gms) {
    $counter++;
    substr $out, pos($in)-1, length($from), $to unless $counter % $every;
};
print $out;
```

If the `$from` and `$to` parameters have different length, you still need to mess a bit with the second parameter of `substr` to make it work correctly.

Comment: How would this handle a hex character input for $to? Also, what would you change to handle the different lengths of $from/$to?

Answer (score 3):

How about a nice, simple `awk` one-liner?

```
awk -v RS=, '{ORS=(++i%3?",":"|");print}' file.csv
```

One minor bug just occurred to me: it will print a `,` or `|` as the very last character. To avoid this, we need to alter it slightly:

```
awk -v RS=, '{ORS=(++i%3?",":"|");print}END{print ""}' file.csv | sed '$d'
```

Comment: *How's that!* (+1) ... It was interesting working out my `sed` minutia, but some `awk` RS magic is *more* interesting..

Comment: Here is a variant which avoids the `ORS` issue. It is pretty much the same as your original version, except that it  processes the seperator at the *prefix* end of the record:   `awk -vRS=, -vORS= '{print pre}; pre=(NR%3)?",":"|"' file.csv`

Comment: This deleted the final line of data. Peter.O's suggestion worked. Does it handle hex?

Comment: @toop In awk `"\xAB"` or the appropriate hex digits is interpreted correctly as the hex number of a character, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @toop: I've noticed that although it works for a single input file, if you have multiple files in the parameter list, it can produce unexpected results (depending on how the file ends ) ... If you ever do want to feed multiple files into the script, it does work by using `cat file1 file2 | awk` or passing a single parameter via process substitution; `awk "{stuff}" <(cat file1 file2)`

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea in bash script :

```
perl -pe 's/,/(++$n % 3 == 0) ? "|" : $&/ge'  data.txt
```

That will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This processes the input file one line at a time (no slurping :)
For hex input, just pass `'\x7C'` or whatever, as `$1`

```
#!/bin/bash  

b="${1:-,}"                             # the "before" field delimiter 
n="${2:-3}"                             # the number of fields in a group
a="${3:-|}"; [[ $a == [\|] ]] && a='\|' # the "after" group delimiter

sed -nr "x;G; /(([^$b]+$b){$((n-1))}[^$b]+)$b/{s//\1$a/g}
         s/.*\n//; h; /.*$a/{s///; x}; p" input_file
```

---

Here it is again, with some comments.

```
sed -nr "x;G    # pat = hold + pat
  /(([^$b]+$b){$((n-1))}[^$b]+)$b/{s//\1$a/g}
  s/.*\n//      # del fields from prev line
  h             # hold = mod*\n
  /.*$a/{ s///  #  pat = unmodified
          x     # hold = unmodified, pat = mod*\n
        }            
  p             # print line"  input_file
```

Comment: How do you pass arguments to the script?

Comment: It is already set up for passing args. The defaults are currently: `script "," 3 "|"` so you only need to call `script` with no args, or just change them

Comment: I time-tested Kevin's `awk` version, and TLP's `perl` version (with 50,000 records). They both run at very close to the same speed... That makes them both about 10 times faster than my `sed` version (not surprising, considering  all that data shuffling `sed` needs to do, once you ask it to do anything involving multiple lines.).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get params and create part of the regex.
my $delim   = "\\" . shift;
my $n       = shift;
my $repl    = shift;
my $wild    = '.*?';
my $pattern = ($wild . $delim) x ($n - 1);

# Slurp.
$/       = undef;
my $text = <>;

# Replace and print.
$text =~ s/($pattern$wild)$delim/$1$repl/sg;
print $text;
```

Comment: @toop The delimiter could be specified in hex: just change the first line to `my $delim = shift` and you can pass in arbitrary regular expression syntax, including hex in the form `\xaa`. The replacement string will be treated as an ordinary string, unless you pass it through `eval`.