# Replace every nth Occurrence in a Perl Script

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file with 10 lines. Each line has the word no_access and only that in it. I found a website that has syntax to replace every nth occurrence of some string. When I try to put it into a script, it spits out errors.

[Replace every Nth occurrence](http://backreference.org/2012/08/22/replace-every-nth-occurrence/)

This is the script I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
my $count = 0; 
s/no_access/(++$count % 3 == 0)?"read":$&/ge;
}
print;
```

However, I get the error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in print.

I tried the script without the print command, but nothing happens. How do I get this script to run and perform the replacement of every third "no_access".

Comment: Question: How are you calling this script? I don't see a filename argument.  Also, the script isn't going to change a file in place, even if it where looping over a file.

Comment: I've just started Perl today. I'm working from this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153302/perl-replace-every-nth-and-multiples-occurrences-of-a-character-with-another

Comment: I'm calling the script like this from the command line: perl Script.pl TextFile.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 0;
my $n = 3;

while (<>) {
    s/no_access/read/ if !( ++$i % $n );
    print;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure I understand how to translate "unless ++$i % $n". Does that mean perform the replacement unless there isn't a remainder?

Comment: @DrewRush - The pattern is *do x unless y (is true)*.  Thus, as long as `++$i % $n` evaluates to `True`, `s/no_access/read/` will not be done.  Perl actually evaluates the above `unless` statement as `(++$i % $n) or s/no_access/read/`.  Since `or` is used, if `++$i % $n` is non-zero, `s/no_access/read/` will never be evaluated (executed).  This is called [short circuit](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355)ing.

Comment: @gatinueta - Each line *is* an occurrence, according to the OP's specs.

Comment: @Kenosis: Correct. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct, just move the variable declaration outside the while loop, and the print inside:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
while (<>) {
        s/no_access/(++$count % 3 == 0)?"read":$&/ge;
        print;
}
```

It then reads from stdin and prints to stdout, changing every 3rd occurrence as you want it to.

If you want to read in a file, change its contents, then write it again, your code could look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
die "usage: $0 <filename>" unless defined $file;
open(IN, "<$file") or die "Can't read $file: $!";
my $count = 0;
my $out = "";
while (<IN>) {
        s/no_access/(++$count % 3 == 0)?"read":$&/ge;
        $out .= $_;
}
close(IN);
open(OUT, ">$file") or die "Can't write $file: $!";
print OUT $out;
close(OUT);
```

Comment: That prints the results out to the command line. How would I get the results to do an in place replacement in the text file?

Comment: There is no "in place" replacement. You can write the new file then change its name to the old name in a wide variety of ways; or you can read in the entire file then open it again for writing. I'll update my answer to show how.