# How to use sed or awk or something similar to replace every odd occurrence of character?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have the following string:

"1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55".

How to use awk, or sed to get

"1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,13.05,24233.55"?

I tried to use

```
sed 's/,/./g' <<< "1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55"
1.0.2.0.3.0.4.0.5.0.6.0.13.05.24233.55
```

and also

```
sed 's/,/./2' <<< "1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55"
1,0.2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55
```

Which replaced the second item only. I need every odd occurrence changed.
For future, what would be the code the replace every odd occurrence of, by . ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is different from the linked post: sed 's/,/./2;P;D;' <<< "1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55" gave the following output: 
     1,0.2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55

Comment: Your title was out of sync with the question. Corrected.

Comment: You may use `sed -E 's/([^,]*),([^,]*)(,|$)/\1.\2\3/g' <<< "1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55"`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/CYKl7J)

Comment: try perl ````"1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55" | perl -pe ' s/,/++$x%2==0?",":"."/ge '
    1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,13.05,24233.55
    ````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any sed that supports EREs via `-E`, e.g. GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ echo "1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,13,05,24233,55" | sed -E 's/,([^,]+(,|$))/.\1/g'
1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,13.05,24233.55
```

The above was inspired by @PesaThe's comment to my original answer.

Comment: Does this solution also work for csv files?

Comment: I have found a solution by googleing in stackoverflow: awk -v RS=, '{ORS=(++i%2?",":".");print}' for the even case for csv files  taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153302/perl-replace-every-nth-and-multiples-occurrences-of-a-character-with-another

Comment: Your input **is** CSV so idk what you're really asking about. The awk script you posted (which has an unnecessary `++i` given that `NR` exists btw) won't do anything better than the sed script I provided (it will however add an undesirable , or . at the end of the output) best I can tell as long as your sample input is truly representative of your real input.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

for the end:

```
sed 's/[,]$/?/' YourFile
```

- putting the `,` between `[]` allow you to remove most of the regex behavior taking litteral value (not for some char like `^` that need to be manage another way
- putting the `$` is telling to refere to end of string

the `g` in your test mean change every occurence, you only wanted 1 and at the end

for the internal:

```
sed -e 's/,/./1;p' \
    -e ':a' \
    -e 's/^\(\([^.]*[.][^,]*,\)*\)\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1\3.\4/
        /[^,]*,[^,.]*,/ ta' YourFile
```

you need a loop and a special test due to alternance existing

Comment: @EdMorton a save before ending the reply, so missing the second part for internal. Same remark for your script that loose double quote and last char (at least like it is showed in description ) :-)